# How to add MDDataTable to MDScreenManager

Tags: kivymd

How to add MDDataTable to MDTopAppBar?

ScreenOne.py:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp

class ScreenOneView(MDScreen):
    pass

class DeliveryTable(MDDataTable):
    pass
```

ScreenOne.kv

```
<ScreenOneView>
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
<DeliveryTable>
    MDDataTable(
        pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
        size_hint=(0.9,0.8),
        check=True,
        rows_num=10,
        column_data = [
            ('No.', dp(20)),
            ('Food',dp(20)),
            ('Calories', dp(20))
        ],
        row_data=[
            (1, 'Burger', 300),
            (2, 'Carrot', 50),
            (1, 'Burger', 300),
            (2, 'Carrot', 50),
            (1, 'Burger', 300),
            (2, 'Carrot', 50),
            (1, 'Burger', 300),
            (2, 'Carrot', 50),
            (1, 'Burger', 300),
            (2, 'Carrot', 50)
        ]
    )
```

I need add table to screen one. MDLabel is working but MDataTable only empty screen.
I'm trying for a few days. I searched the internet, documentation, YT - Nothing. ChatGPT is not usable